# How to structure pages in MVC 3.0 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm quite new to the MVC world. I have a MVC 3.0 application with multiple pages for each divisions below:

```
1. Division A
    a. Page A
    b. Page B
    c. Page C
    d. Page D

2. Division B
    a. Page A
    b. Page B

3. Division C
    a. Page A
    b. Page B   
4. Division D
    a. Page A
    b. Page B
    c. Page C
    d. Page D
```

Each division pages has their own dynamic page contents which they receive in JSON format from controller. The main page contains a drop down from which user can select one of the division. When they select a specific division the page should load with specific division contents.

Questions:

1. Should I create specific views folder for each division?
2. Should each of the above division have their own controller?
3. Is there any way in MVC 3.0, where when user selects on Division B redirect the user to Division B index.cshtml page?
4. As shown above divisions have their own pages. What's the best way to track which division the user is at and which page should be loaded when user request Page A?
5. Or, should I have one Division control and one view where json with data content are passed from action.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't make a new controller for each division. You might make one Division controller and use a query string value to determine which one you want to display data for.

If you create a controller for each division then you make it difficult to scale your application. What would happen if the user wants to create/delete a division? etc.

Comment: Thanks @Nick, are you suggesting one Division controller and with in it it has many actions and relevant views?

Comment: What type of actions are you suggesting? I'm not familiar with your application. If you have an action that lists, creates, updates a division it would belong to the division controller. If it handled billing it might go in a billing controller. I hope this helps.